# Generate new code coverage for a single file without clearing all other coverage reports in PHPUnit

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, code-coverage

**First the question:**
In PHPUnit 3.5, is there a way to generate a coverage report for a single test without the report for the entire test suite being overwritten. I.e. only update the coverage report for the affected files? I still want the output to go to the same folder.

**For those that want a bit of background:**

Working with PHPUnit 3.5, I have a project which retroactively needs to be covered with unit tests. Now in order to know which classes still need tests I run the entire test suite and generate a html coverage report on it. Because running the complete suite takes some time, I would like to avoid having to run it every time I want to check which tests still need to be implemented. But at the same time I also want the coverage report for the unit test that I'm currently working on, so that I can make sure I'm executing each line of code in a class (this of course is very fast back and forth, so it makes no sense to run the entire suite just to generate this report). I can generate the report for a single test, and I can generate it for the entire suite. But what I'm looking for is a hybrid, which would allow me to first generate a report for the entire suite, and then just update the report with coverage information for the test I'm currently working on.

I've set up a ruby script which will simply run the test for the current file I'm working on and generate a coverage report on that file. But working like that, it always resets the coverage report for all other files also, even if the test did not execute anything in those classes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible natively, but if you can figure out how to regenerate the HTML from the XML coverage data files you could modify your script to

1. Copy the coverage XML for a full run to a staging area.
2. When running a single test, copy over the new XML files to that area. This will necessarily not merge coverage from two tests that cover the same class, but I'm guessing from your description that you're covering a single class from each test and vice versa.
3. Rebuild the HTML from the XML. You might be able to figure out how to do this by looking at the source, but I doubt it's possible natively either.

Comment: Thanks, although a bit unfortunate that the correct answer is that it's not possible :( I'll post back if I figure out how to realize your suggestion.